# VirtualBox Port Forwarding Issue

Tags: virtualbox, port-forwarding

I face an issue with port-forwarding and VirtualBox. I launch a linux vm using vagrant. SSH was already working with the port-forwading. The vm network is NAT.

Then I launch my flask application running on 5000. I declare the port-forwarding in VirtualBox.

[image]

But I can't access 127.0.0.1:5000 on my host. Host is Windows 7.

I already tried to reboot the vm and declare 127.0.0.1 as host ip.

Comment: if you are using NAT why do you need the port forward from your machine? you should be able to access the vm by it's IP. Now having that said, if your port forward works for 2222 to 22 and the second port forward does "not work" than it could be that your vm is blocking port 5000 or is using some redirection. so you should check with telnet 127.0.0.1 5000 if you get a response.

Comment: This is what I get when I curl in my vm. It responds as expected.
curl 127.0.0.1:5000
testvagrant@precise64:~$

 telnet 127.0.0.1 5000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.

Same thing with telnet.

Comment: I assume you ran this on your host. So you get a response meaning the network part (port forward) is not a problem. Maybe you should check the flask app logs.

Comment: no I run this on my guest to check if my app is running.
I have no response if I run this on my host

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your second comment. You have to check from your host machine. If it will not work then it is probably a firewall problem.

Comment: on the guest vm check `netstat -an | grep :5000` to see where your app is listening. If it listens only on localhost then it will not work!

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
is the response to netstat -an | grep :5000

Comment: your flask app is listening only on localhost, so it will not respond to the port forwarded requests as they do not come from localhost in the perspective of your guest vm

Comment: So How should I do if I want to access my flask app on my host ? I thought that port forwarding will allow me to do that ?

Comment: port forwarding is only a part of it, see [here for flask configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/flask-configure-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network) to listen on all network interfaces. And to remind you, in my first comment I told that you should be able to access it by using the vm's IP. Port forwarding is more useful if you want to allow access from your LAN to the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of the troubleshooting process in the comments:

The problem was not in port forwarding, it was that the flask app was listening only on localhost on the guest vm. After correcting the startup of the app to listen on all interfaces, the OP resolved his issue and was able to connect from his host.